# LightHTTPD; how do i disable http so only https is available on a single port?

Tags: http, ssl, webserver, https, httpd

I have a project that should be available only through ssl connection. It's being served by Lighthttpd, but I can't figure out how to set up the ssl on the port.

When I use the guides I find with google, lighthttpd tells me that the port/socket it's attempting to use is already bound (I'm using port 8080). This is no mystery since it's serving normal http on that port.

I *could* bind 'http' to a different port, but I really don't want unused/listening ports lying around willy nilly :)

My question is if and how I can disable the 'http' serving, and only use https with ssl (preferably only on the vhost I've configured)?

Comment: I see now that SSL won't let me have ssl on one vhost name only, but this is not really a problem since it's only serving this one project. So my question is now; how do i disable http so only https is used?

Comment: Well. All i had to do was add  ssl.engine  = "enable"  and  ssl.pemfile = "/<path>/<to>/>my>/<cert>.pem"  to *lighthttpd.conf*... Now it no longer responds to http, only https.

Comment: If you find a solution yourself, post it as an answer, not as a comment.

Comment: Sorry, i think i was unable to do that because there was a time set on how fast i could answer my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
ssl.engine = "enable"
ssl.pemfile = "/<path>/<to>/<my>/<cert>.pem"
```

to lighthttpd.conf